# Selenium-python drag and drop not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I tried to automate drag and drop option using selenium 
but below code is working fine without errors

```
source=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//source path")
dest=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//destination path")
action=ActionChains(driver)     
action.drag_and_drop(source,dest).perform()
```

problem: element is moved to destination but it is not dropped there (still cursor holds the element)
and no more mouse action can be performed (ex:click)

Answer (score 2):

Try another way with `.click_and_hold`:

```
ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(source).move_to_element(dest).release(dest).click(dest).perform()
```

Remove `.click(dest)` if you want only move without click the element.

Comment: No, I tried with that but problem still not resolved

Comment: Is possible to share the site?

Comment: sorry I can't do that. that is private site